# How to go to first page after(before) sorting in extJs grid

Tags: extjs

I have extJs 4.1 grid with paging. For this grid applied remoteSort(maybe remoting style of sorting doesn't matter) behaviour. After sort click(click on header) I wanna go to first page. How can I achive this? Maybe exists presort callback in what I can cancel loading data and forward loading to first page with store.loadPage(1)?

P.S. Sorry for english.

Comment: you should improve your acceptace rate, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

This code is part of the FiltersFeature.js file.
Take a look at how when to specify (local: false) it goes to first page automagically ;)

```
reload : function () {
    var me = this,
        store = me.view.getStore();

    if (me.local) {
        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filterBy(me.getRecordFilter());
        store.sort();
    } else {
        me.deferredUpdate.cancel();
        if (store.buffered) {
            store.pageMap.clear();
        }
        store.loadPage(1);
    }
}
```

What you have to do is configure the feature with local: false.